# Checkbox with Jquery map function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code,

```
...

<input type="hidden" name="unchecked"  id="unchecked" value="" />
<?php
    $ind = 1;
    foreach($array as $v){
?>

<input class="checkbox checked" id="checked_<?php echo $ind; ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"/>

<?php
    $ind++;
    }
?>

...
```

I want to store checkbox values as comma seperated in hidden box. so i tried with the following  jquery ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){    
        $("input.checked").click(function(){  
            //alert($(this).val());
            $("input#unchecked").val($.map($("input[id^='checked_']"), function( item ) {
                return $(item).val();
            }).join(",")); 
        });
    });  
</script>
```

The above script stores all values of checkbox when i click any one of check box. what i done wrong on this. kindly advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$("input[id^='checked_']")
```

to

```
$("input[id^='checked_']:checked")
```

Or use the below:

Select the checked: `$("input[id^='checked_']").is(':checked')`

Select the unchecked: `$("input[id^='checked_']").not(':checked')`

Comment: also now i want to store value when user uncheck the checked check box.i am using this $("input[id^='stchecked_'][checked=false]") .This is not working